# Placing data to API URL

Tags: android, api

I'm stuck at setting new data and send each data (location,message,datetime,id) to API URL. My code is not working at the moment,

```
 public void SendData(){
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    String datefinal = dateFormat.format(date).toString();
    List<NameValuePair> listOfParameters = new LinkedList<>();
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        URI uri = new URIBuilder("http://192.168.1.212/mobile_alerts_api.php?location=&msg=&datetime=&id=")
                .addParameter("location", "1")
                .addParameter("msg", message)
                .addParameter("datetime", datefinal)
                .addParameter("id", "1")
                .addParameters(listOfParameters)
                .build();
                Log.e("URI",String.valueOf(listOfParameters));
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
        Log.e("HttpGetq ",String.valueOf(httpGet));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(uri));
        Log.e("URI",String.valueOf(uri));
        httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: please show your error message!

Comment: hi @KimKevin im not getting any error message, the problem is the code cant  record on the API

Comment: you mean you can't get response from server? what do you mean 'record'?

Comment: i need to send the location, datetime, message, and id to API

Comment: Share your log here.

Comment: hi @SamirBhatt i've try to log it, but the logcat doesn't display any log

Comment: yeap. what do you have problem exactly? which part? server or client? we need more information.

Comment: sorry for not elaborating the question, i just want to send the data to API, i've read alot here and google and try to construct the code above, but its bot working, its not been adding to database.

Comment: my plan B is set the URL from
http://192.168.1.212/mobile_alerts_api.php?location=&msg=&datetime=&id=

to

http://192.168.1.212/mobile_alerts_api.php?location=1&msg=" + message +  "&datetime=" + datefinal + "&id=1

Comment: If this code executed or not? Have you debug for it?

Comment: @SamirBhatt i've executed but no error was occured and no log displayed on logcat

Comment: why not using retrofit?

Comment: @faruk i have tried this code (sorry, dont know how to comment codes here)

` Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.212/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();`